# How i can solve NULL value problem when selectingfrom a table?

Tags: sql, database

I have **students** TABLE with 4 3 columns:

1. *first* which has the first name
2. *middle* which has the middle name and NULL VALUES
3. *last* the last name
4. *house* the name of the house
5. *birth* the date of birth of each person

I want to SELECT all records WHERE house is *Gryffindor* including records which has middle value is NULL.

```
SELECT first || " " || middle || " " || last || "," || " " || "born" || " " || birth AS birth
FROM students
WHERE house LIKE "Gryffindor"
ORDER BY last, first;
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database that you use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One quick and dirty workaround here would be to use `COALESCE` against all the name components:

```
SELECT COALESCE(first, '') || ' ' ||
       COALESCE(middle || ' ', '') ||
       COALESCE(last, '') || ', born ' || birth AS birth
FROM students
WHERE house = 'Gryffindor'  -- assuming you want a specific house
ORDER BY last, first;
```

Comment: it works but there are more spaces in the output between the first name and the last name if the middle name was NULL

Comment: @OdaiKiwan I have made an update which at least covers this problem specifically for the `middle` field possibly being null.